# Parsing just first result with beautiful soup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I have the following code which succesfully pulls links, titles, etc. for podcast episodes. How would I go about just pulling the first one it comes to (i.e. the latest episode) and then immediately stop and produce just that result? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
def get_playable_podcast(soup):
"""
@param: parsed html page            
"""
subjects = []

for content in soup.find_all('item'):

    try:        
        link = content.find('enclosure')
        link = link.get('url')
        print "\n\nLink: ", link

        title = content.find('title')
        title = title.get_text()

        desc = content.find('itunes:subtitle')
        desc = desc.get_text()

        thumbnail = content.find('itunes:image')
        thumbnail = thumbnail.get('href')

    except AttributeError:
        continue

    item = {
            'url': link,
            'title': title,
            'desc': desc,
            'thumbnail': thumbnail
    }

    subjects.append(item) 

return subjects

def compile_playable_podcast(playable_podcast):
"""
@para: list containing dict of key/values pairs for playable podcasts
"""
items = []

for podcast in playable_podcast:
    items.append({
        'label': podcast['title'],
        'thumbnail': podcast['thumbnail'],
        'path': podcast['url'],
        'info': podcast['desc'],
        'is_playable': True,
})

return items
```

Comment: If you just want the first element, use `soup.find()` instead of `soup.find_all()`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @John Gordon is completely correct. 
@John Gordon pointed out that:

```
soup.find()
```

will always display the first found item (for you thats perfectly fine, when you want to scrape the "latest episode").
However, imagine you just wanted to select the second, third, fourth, etc. item of your BeautifulSoup. Then you could do that with the following line of code:

```
soup.find()[0] # This will works the same way as soup.find() and displays the first item
```

When you replace the 0 by any other number (e.g. 4) you solely get the choosen (in this example fourth) item ;).